# check port status and the send email

Tags: php, shell, email

I have one shell script which check the port status every minute. If the status of port is down then it will send email. But this will send email every minute until port is again up. But I want to send email after 30 minutes from 1st mail sent. How can i do this? I call PHP file from shell script to send mail.

```
nc -v -z -w 10 192.168.50.34 5038;

output=$?
# echo $output
php=`which php`

dt=`date`;


$php send_ast_status.php $output $dt


if [ $output == "0" ];
then 

#   echo 'asterisk is running'
    /etc/init.d/asterisk 'stop'

else 
#       echo 'asterisk not running'
      /etc/init.d/asterisk 'start'

fi
```

Comment: Store the last email sent time in a database / on file?

Comment: You need to save the state of the last check somewhere, in a database or in a simple file. Only with that information you can decide if a change has occurred.

Comment: e.g. use a sendmail file put timestamp into it and then check it

Comment: Showing your script helps,  [edit] your question.. What did you try, what part of the code does not work?

Comment: nc -v -z -w 10 192.168.50.34 5038;
output=$?
# echo $output
php=`which php`
dt=`date`;

$php send_ast_status.php $output $dt


if [ $output == "0" ];
then 
 
#  echo 'asterisk is running'
 /etc/init.d/asterisk 'stop'

else 
#       echo 'asterisk not running'
      /etc/init.d/asterisk 'start'

fi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type the following command: telnet example.com 25 View Results:

If Port 25 is not blocked, you will get a successful 220 response (text may vary).

Trying 64.13.192.208... Connected to example.com.

Escape character is '^]'. 220 cl34.gs01.gridserver.com ESMTP Exim 4.63 Tue, 24 Jun 2008 13:45:04 -0700

If Port 25 is blocked, you will get a connection error or no response at all.

Trying 64.13.192.208... telnet: connect to address 64.13.192.208: Connection refused telnet: Unable to connect to remote host